# OpenCL - clEnqueueNDRangeKernel - output array becomes input array

Tags: c, buffer, opencl

I perform a 5-point stencil operation on a 2D array until getting a convergence computed on this 2D array. So I have multiple iterations (until convergence) and for each iteration, I am calling `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` function to compute the new values of 2D input array.

Actually, I manipulate 1D array since kernel code doesn't support 2D (at least, I believe).

My issue is that I don't know how to do the affectation between output and input array. After a computing iteration (stencil operation), I want to assign the output to the input for the next iteration.

But I am confused about how to achieve this.

Below the function used in my main loop :

```
while(!convergence)
    {
      step = step + 1;

      Compute_Stencil(command_queue, global_item_size, local_item_size, kernel, x0_mem_obj, x_mem_obj, r_mem_obj, x_input, r, size_x, size_y, &error) ;

      convergence = sqrt(error);

      if ((convergence<epsilon) || (step>maxStep)) break;
    }
```

where `x0_mem_obj` is the buffer associated to `x_input` array and `x_mem_obj` is associated to `x_ouput` array.

and the `Compute_Stencil` function that interests me :

```
void Compute_Stencil(cl_command_queue command_queue, size_t* global_item_size, size_t* local_item_size, cl_kernel kernel, cl_mem x0_mem_obj, cl_mem x_mem_obj, cl_mem r_mem_obj, double* x, double* r, int size_x, int size_y, double* error)
{

status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 2, NULL,
        global_item_size, local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

 // Read the buffer back to the array
  if(clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, x_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        (size_x+2) * (size_y+2) * sizeof(double), x, 0, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in clEnqueueReadBuffer with x_mem_obj\n");


  if(clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, r_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        (size_x+2) * (size_y+2) * sizeof(double), r, 0, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in clEnqueueReadBuffer with r_mem_obj\n");


  status = clFlush(command_queue);
  if(status)
  {fprintf(stderr,"Failed to flush command Queue\n");
    exit(-1);}

  if(clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, x0_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        (size_x+2) * (size_y+2) * sizeof(cl_double), x, 0, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in clEnqueueWriteuffer with x0_mem_obj\n");

 // Set new Argument - Outputs become Inputs
  status = clSetKernelArg(
      kernel,
      5,
      sizeof(cl_mem),
      (void*)&x0_mem_obj);

...
```

I think this is not the best method because for each iteration, I have to read the output `x_mem_obj` buffer to `x_input` (with `clEnqueueReadBuffer`) and write `x_input` to `x0_mem_obj` buffer (with `clEnqueueWWriteBuffer`) and finally set the `x0_mem_obj` buffer to the kernelArg (5th argument) : this buffer represents the input `x0_mem_obj` in main :

```
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&x0_mem_obj);
```

I think this is not the good method because performances are very bad ( I think Read and Write Buffer operations cost a lot of time).

I try not to use ReadBuffer and WriteBuffer in `Compute_Stencil` function and put directly the output buffer `x_mem_obj` in the 5th argument for the next call :

```
 status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 2, NULL,
        global_item_size, local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

status = clFlush(command_queue);

// Set new Argument - Outputs become Inputs
  status = clSetKernelArg(
      kernel,
      5,
      sizeof(cl_mem),
      (void*)&x_mem_obj);
```

But the results are not valid.

How can I transfer simply, after a NDRangeKernel call, the output array to the input array for the next call of NDRangeKernel?

### Update 1

@doqtor, thanks for your answer but I have to specify that, after the computing of new values (i.e after the call of NDRangeKernel), I need to assign the new calculated values to the input, but I think I don't need to replace the input array by the output one : the output buffer will be systematically overwritted by the new values calculated from the input buffer values.

In my kernel code, I have the following arguments :

```
__kernel void kernelHeat2D(const double diagx, const double diagy,
                                 const double weightx, const double weighty,
                                 const int size_x,
                                 __global double* tab_current,
                                 __global double* tab_new,
                                 __global double* r)
```

where `tab_new` is the output array and `tab_current` the input one. `tab_current` is the 6th argument (so numbered by 5 in `clSetKernelArg`).

That's why, after NDRangeKernel call,  I think that I have only to use :

```
// Set new Argument - Outputs become Inputs
  status = clSetKernelArg(
      kernel,
      5,
      sizeof(cl_mem),
      (void*)&x_mem_obj);
```

### Update 2

The method above in **Update 1** doesn't work : I get at the execution random difference values  in array "`r`" (whose buffer is `r_mem_obj` in my code ). This array allows to compute the convergence, so I get different number of steps at each execution.

To work, I have to put explicitly in main loop :

```
while (!convergence) {

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel();

// Read output buffer and put it into xOutput
clEnqueueReadBuffer( x_mem_obj, xOutput);

// Read error buffer and put it into r
clEnqueueReadBuffer( r_mem_obj, r);

// Write output array to input buffer
clEnqueueWriteBuffer( x0_mem_obj, xOutput)

// put input buffer into input argument for next call of NDRangeKernel
status = clSetKernelArg(
      kernel,
      5,
      sizeof(cl_mem),
       (void*)&x0_mem_obj);
}
```

I would like to avoid using `ReadBuffer` and `WriteBuffer` (to force setting `xOutput` to input `x0_mem_obj` buffer) because it gives poor performances from a time execution point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you set output as input only and then you have the same buffer as input and output. You need to swap buffers:

```
buffer1 = create buffer 1
buffer2 = create buffer 2

clEnqueueWriteBuffer(..., buffer1, ...);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(..., buffer2, ...);

cl_mem *ptrInput = &buffer1;
cl_mem *ptrOutput = &buffer2;

for(..)
{
    clSetKernelArg(..., inputIdx, ptrInput, ...);
    clSetKernelArg(..., outputIdx, ptrOutout, ...);
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(...);

    // swap buffers
    cl_mem *ptrTpm = ptrInput;
    ptrInput = ptrOutput;
    ptrOuput = ptrTmp;
}

// ...
// Read results data back
clEnqueueReadBuffer(..., ptrInput, ...); // read from ptrInput because we did extra swap
```

Comment: I understand that I have to set output buffer to input buffer but I don't understand when you do ptrOutput = ptrTmp, the output buffer is not automatically overwritten after the call of NDRangeKernel ? it seems that I only need to put the new input before this calling.

Comment: I changed `double` into `cl_mem` in case that confused you. Also bear in mind that `clSetKernelArg` takes a pointer to a buffer, not the whole buffer. Think how would you do buffer swapping without copying data in C/C++, this is similar approach here.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have understood : I thought that I only needed to set output buffer to input buffer for the next call of NDRangeKernel :this way, I put the same buffer before calling kernel code. But in my kernel code, I compute the next value (the output value) by :                             int iy = get_global_id(0)+1;
int ix = get_global_id(1)+1;
output_array[iy(size_x+2)+ix]                                                         =function(input_array);

Comment: So there are conflicts between work-items threads. Finally, the solution is to, in addition to set output buffer to input buffer, to set also the input buffer to output one before the call of NDRangeKernel in order to avoid conflicts of overwritten values, that's why I need to swap :  this explanation is right ?

Comment: Someone could answer please ?